# Referencing the range of an icon/shape

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a macro to a magnifying glass icon.

This macro will copy the value of a cell four columns to the left relative to the cell that contains the magnifying glass icon.

How do I reference the range that contains an object like the magnifying glass?

The idea is to copy the magnifying glass into every row in that column.

For example, in the image below when I click on the magnifying glass it would call the assigned VBA procedure and copy the value "LA COE".

Magnifying_Glass_Example
[image]

Comment: Right click the icon --> Assign Macro?

Answer (score 1):

Every shape has a `TopLeftCell` and a `BottomRightCell` property that you can use for that:

```
Sub CopyCellValue()
    Dim s As Shape
    Debug.Print Application.Caller
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    s.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -4).Copy  'Or whatever
End Sub
```

`Application.Caller` will then hold the name of the shape to which the macro is assigned, so you can assign the exact same macro to each magnifying class.

Just make sure that your icons are truly placed in the cells you want. This can especially bite you if you try to align them pixel-perfect to the corners (e.g. dragging one of the shape corners with alt pressed), in which case `TopLeftCell` / `BottomRightCell` might refer to adjacent cells instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response! I'll give this a try.